# A claim on multivariate t

Tags: probability

Say we got a random vector $\textbf{X}=(X_1,...,X_d)\in t_\nu(0,\textbf{I},\nu)$.

Is the claim $\sum_{i=1}^d X_i =^d \sqrt{d}Z$, where $Z\in t_\nu$ correct and why?

Comment: If I understand you right, you have $d$ independent $t_{\nu}$ distributions, and you are wondering if their sum is equal in distribution to a $\sqrt{d} t_{\nu}$ (being loose in notation)? My knee jerk reaction is that this is not true, since that would make $t$ distribution $\alpha$-stable, which I don't think it is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution

Comment: yes that's it. I have to accept that it is correct to keep studying the material below. Could you think of any possible reason for that?

Comment: I am confused by your above comment. Please clarify. Like I said, I think the claim is incorrect.

Comment: Although this is certainly true for some $d$ and some $\nu$ (for instance, whenever $d=1$ or $\nu=1$), it cannot be true in general for otherwise the Central Limit Theorem would be violated: as $d$ grows large and $\nu \gt 2$, the distribution on the left hand side must grow close to Normal, with [rapidly decreasing tails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), whereas the distribution on the right hand side has tails that do not decrease rapidly no matter what $\nu$ might be.

Comment: in some other material i found this:
if $\textbf{X}\in spherical$ then $P(X_1+...+X_d\leq t)=P(\sqrt{d}X_1\leq t)$

Comment: Is the meaning that $X$ has a multivariate $T$ distribution (an elliptical distribution). The components are then **not** independent!